# Getting No goals have been specified for this build ERROR while running my karate framework scripts KARATE | MAVEN

Tags: maven, karate

I am using Intellij with java 17 and maven 3.9.0 version to run my karate framework with maven command:

mvn clean test -Dtest=Runner -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=test"

my pom.xml have this below versions

UTF-8

```
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <java.version>1.8.0_162</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <karate.version>1.1.0</karate.version>
    <jaxb.version>2.1</jaxb.version>
    <gatling.plugin.version>3.0.5</gatling.plugin.version>
</properties>
```

after hitting mvn clean test -Dtest=Runner -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=test"

Always getting below error:

BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-s
ources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-res
ources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in
the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean,
post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sou
rces, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.

I tried by downgrading my java version to 1.8 but no luck.

Comment: Please post the complete command line output.

Comment: I also suggest to OP to search other threads, yes once in a while maven is hard to figure and OS, JDK, versions etc matter: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bkarate%5d%20maven&searchOn=3